# /bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found in development ENV reactjs

Tags: reactjs, docker

I want to use Docker in development mode, This is my Docker file.

```
FROM node:18.12.1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .


EXPOSE 3000


CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

and my docker-compose is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mlm_frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

I have an error **/bin/sh: 1: react-scripts: not found**

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding everything the Dockerfile does.  You may as well use the unmodified `node` image as your base, at which point you may as well use Node without Docker.  What benefits are you hoping to get from using Docker here?